# Why is it impossible to make a mixed-state qubit into a pure-state qubit?

Tags: bloch-sphere, purification

How is it impossible to make a mixed-state qubit (having Bloch vector of length $l < 1$) into a pure-state qubit (having Bloch vector of length $l' = 1$) via a quantum operation that is invertible?

Can anyone give a proof of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to have an operation sending a specific mixed input into a specific pure output. Trivial case in point: just throw away the input state and replace it with $|0\rangle$ (or any other state). Mathematically, that's the replacement channel $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}(\rho)|0\rangle\!\langle 0|$.

It's not possible to have an operation sending any mixed input into a pure state, with the only exception of a replacement channel. One way to see it easily is to assume $\Phi$ is such an operation. Then it sends $\mathbb{P}_0\equiv |0\rangle\!\langle0|$ and $\mathbb{P}_1$ into pure states, meaning $\Phi(\mathbb{P}_0)$ and $\Phi(\mathbb{P}_1)$ are pure states. But then $\Phi(\frac12(\mathbb{P}_0+\mathbb{P}_1))=\frac12(\Phi(\mathbb{P}_0)+\Phi(\mathbb{P}_1))$, and thus the mixed state $\frac12(\mathbb{P}_0+\mathbb{P}_1)$ is sent to a mixture of two pure states. Therefore, unless $\Phi(\mathbb{P}_0)=\Phi(\mathbb{P}_1)$, you built a mixed state that is *not* sent to a pure state. And if $\Phi(\mathbb{P}_0)=\Phi(\mathbb{P}_1)$, then repeat the above reasoning with any other pair of pure states that are not sent to the same output, and you got another mixed state that is not sent to a pure state. The only remaining possibility is that $\Phi$ sends every pure state into the same output, in which case it's a replacement channel of the form $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}(\rho)\mathbb{P}_\psi$.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I'll add another one that I like

Comment: Yes, I agree but purification of that mixed state is only possible if we add some ancillae reference and try to purify the joint system then discard that ancillae by partially tracing out and then calculating the purity. Is my argument wrong?

Comment: @SudhirKumar I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. Sure, these will generally be non-unitary channels, so if you want to implement them via a unitary evolution you need some ancillary degree of freedom, if that's what you're trying to say

Comment: @glS Yes what you are referring that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a quantum operation that takes any state with a Bloch vector of length $l<1$ and converts it into a state with a Bloch vector pointing in the same direction but with $l=1$. This operation would not know what to do with a vector of length $l=0$, because it points in all directions, so the operation cannot be defined.